# Windows Media player object z-index

Tags: object, embed, media-player

What makes windows media player layer over my drop menu page elements?  It doesn't seem to help if I change the z-index for the media player object.  I have a z-index of 99 for my drop down menu page elements and of 40 for the object.  This problem only happens when the video is running.  When it isn't running the drop down menu elements show on top of the object.  Here is the HTML.

```
<div id="player" style="position: relative; top: 20px; left: 35px; width: 64.5%; border: 2px solid grey; z-index: 40;">
    <object id="MediaPlayer" width="100%" height="377" classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; z-index: 40;" type="application/x-oleobject">
    <param name="uiMode" value="full" />
    <param name="AutoStart" value="FALSE" />
    <param name="AllowChangeDisplaySize" value="TRUE" />
    <param name="AutoSize" value="TRUE" />
    <param name="Volume" value="100" />
    <param name="URL" value=mms://bstreamlivewm.fplive.net/bstreamlive-live/bstream2 />
    <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" name="MediaPlayer" src=mms://bstreamlivewm.fplive.net/bstreamlive-live/bstream2 width="100%" height="377" showcontrols="1" showtracker="1" autostart="0" volume="100" />              
    </object>                   
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What worked for me was `<param name="windowlessVideo" value="true" >` in the `<object>` tag and `windowlessVideo="true"` in the `<embed>` tag.  I did not have to specify the wmode parameter.  Here is the HTML that worked.

```
    <object id="MediaPlayer" width="100%" height="377" classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; 

background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;" type="application/x-oleobject">
      <param name="uiMode" value="full" />
      <param name="AutoStart" value="FALSE" />
      <param name="AllowChangeDisplaySize" value="TRUE" />
      <param name="AutoSize" value="TRUE" />
      <param name="Volume" value="100" />
      <param name="URL" value=mms://bstreamlivewm.fplive.net/bstreamlive-live/bstream2 />
          <!-- Be careful with opaque.  The adobe documentation isn't clear about what it does for layering -->
          <!-- Documentation about OBJECT and EMBED at http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html -->
          <!-- param name="wmode" value="opaque" / -->
          <param name="windowlessVideo" value="true" />
          <embed windowlessVideo="true" type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" 

name="MediaPlayer" src=mms://bstreamlivewm.fplive.net/bstreamlive-live/bstream2 width="100%" height="377" showcontrols="1" 

showtracker="1" autostart="0" volume="100" />              
     </object>
```

Comment: Nice! That gets the embed Windows Media Player behind the drop down menus for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

None of these work for Google Chrome.  ASP menus always go to the background when a windows media player is involved.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into the wmode param,http://slightlymore.co.uk/flash-and-the-z-index-problem-solved/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The site streaming this video seems to be down.  If this fixes the problem, I will update.

Comment: What worked for me was `<param name="windowlessVideo" value="true" >` in the `<object>` tag and `windowlessVideo="true"` in the `<embed>` tag.